# Retrofit 400 bad request caused by Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Hi I am using `retrofit + rxandroid` in my app. So here  I have method to make to chain requests

```
public void requestToken(String token,String push_token){
    api.getApi().signIn(token,push_token)
            .map(signInModel -> {
                SharedPreferencesHelper.setLoggedIn();
             SharedPreferencesHelper.setCurrentUserToken(signInModel.getData().getToken());//this line cause 400 bad request
                return api.getApi().getUser(signInModel.getData().getToken());
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onError: " + e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(User user) {
                    UserData data = user.getUserdata();

                }
            });

}
```

can't get why   `SharedPreferencesHelper.setCurrentUserToken(signInModel.getData().getToken());` **causes 400 bad request retrofit error**. Without this it works perfectly.

This is my api interface

```
  public interface Api {


        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/auth/digits/signin")
        public Observable<SignInModel>
        signIn(@Field("digits_token") String digits_token, @Field("push_token") String push_token);

        @GET("/user/get")
        public User
        getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization_header);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with requestInterceptor. Actually don't know why shared preferences caused it but it was my bad sending Header which was null

```
public SapronApi() {

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(request -> request.addHeader("Authorization",SharedPreferencesHelper.getToken()))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    mApi = restAdapter.create(Api.class);

}


public SapronApi(Boolean dummy){

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    mApi = restAdapter.create(Api.class);
}
```

creating api call without static header solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

400 sounds like the specific error code that you are getting from your server. You can try debugging by adding loglevel on Retrofit.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(NetworkCalls.BASE_URL)
    .client(client)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)              // <--- Add this line
    .build();
```

With the loglevel, you can possibly see some error json back from your server.

Example:

```
{"statusCode":400,"message":"Some parameters are missing"}
```

NOTE: This FULL loglevel is debugging purpose and I think you should disable it for production release.